# what's the difference between setstatus(500) and senderror(500)

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee

When writing servlet, I could use
`response.setStatus(500)` and `response.sendError(500)`, what's the difference between those two?

Answer (score 9):

There's another subtle difference between the two methods at least in Servlet 2.4+:

`response.sendError(500)` will redirect to the configured error page (in `web.xml`) for that status code whereas `response.setStatus(500)` assumes you are providing the response body and the container does not check for a matching error page declaration.

Comment: I use the `response.setStatus(SC_UNAUTHORIZED)` solution to provide meaningful JSON on *Unauthorized* error instead of the Tomcat's default. I'm also calling `response.flushBuffer()` just after it so the response is committed and can't be further modified. I'm not sure this is the best solution to tackle the default error pages (probably not), but it's simple.

Answer (score 4):

`setStatus` can be overruled by a consecutive `setStatus` with another code. In contrast, `sendError` immediately sends the error code to the client and cannot be undone. For errors, you should rather use `sendError`.

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendError(int)